# Get result from R (calling R libraries) to Java

Tags: r, tabulizer

My question is the following:

- On my machine ***in R studio terminal*** I am running next lines:

```
library(tabulizer)
library(tabulizerjars)

pdf <- "path_to_file"
result <- extract_tables(pdf)
```

- How to get "result" (it's a list) to java program?

I'd like to use that result in my separate java script (I am running Eclipse).

If needed more clarifications, I am glad to provide.